# After If blook it doesn't select entire row if it is value are true

Tags: excel, vba

I need to select entire last row when value true but it doen't work. Help me.

```
  Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
     Dim erow, lastrow, i As Long
     lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
     For i = 2 To lastrow
     If Cells(i, 1) = Date And Cells(i, 2) = "Sales" Then
     Rows(lastrow).Select
    Selection.Copy
    End If
    Next
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code with only a tiny change:

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
    Dim erow As Long, lastrow As Long, i As Long

    lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lastrow
        If Cells(i, 1) = Date And Cells(i, 2) = "Sales" Then
            Rows(lastrow).Select
            Selection.Copy
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

and it worked !

As you see, it found *True* on row #7 and copied the last row *(row #21)*:

[image]